# z-index on two fixed elements is not working

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have two fixed containers, `#meta` and `#meta-container`, where `#meta` shall always be on the foreground, as it is a global control-element.

My code looks like this

```css
#meta-container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0; right:0;
  bottom:0; top: 0;
  background-color: red;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}

#meta {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 40%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 25px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="meta">
      <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  </span>
  #meta
</div>
<div id="meta-container" class="slidein">
  #meta-container
</div>
```

But `span#meta` is not displayed on top of `div#meta-container`. I did not re-assign `z-index` somewhere. I also changed the `z-index` values for testing but it did not help. What am I doing wrong?

So long - happy coding.

(1) Edit: Corrected spelling in code snippet. Snippet now working (unfortunately not my code).

Comment: Your code snippet, when run, shows two lines of two dots each - care to be _a little_ more specific about what the issue is supposed to be?

Comment: I actually did not realize that I added a snippet. Simply wanted to demonstrate code. However, for the sake of completeness I will edit the snippet so that it will be more meaningful.

Comment: SOLVED: `span#meta` was nested within other containers (e.g. the div mentioned above). After I refactored it to be "on the same level" as `div#span-container` the positioning now works for me. Thanks to all for the help. Thanks to wscourge for giving the question a smoother markup! ;)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is adding `top` and `left` styles to overlay them:

```css
#meta-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#meta {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="meta">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
  </span>
  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
</div>
<div id="meta-container" class="slidein">
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like your snippet suffers from the same "buggy" behavior mine is:  The line of "a"s  that is supposed to be the below element is stacked on top of the b-line (It at least looks like that when I select part of the text). Thank you anyway for taking the time to answer, I gave the #meta element a left-value of 0 to follow your approach without success.

Answer (score 0):

```
#meta-container {
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  . . .
}

#meta {
  position: fixed;
  . . .
}
```

--

```
<div id="meta">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>

    <div id="meta-container" class="slidein">
      ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: randmin: you can see above answer as example in jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vgvcjd87/1/

Comment: I need both elements to be of fixed position. Your answer works great, if one of the elements is of relative position.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#meta{
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
 }
 
 #meta-container{
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 25%;
    color: red;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="meta">
  <span>
    meta box
  </span>
 
</div>

<div id="meta-container" class="slidein">
meta container box
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution is aiming on two elements of position relative / absolute respectiively, I however need both elements to be fixed.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you need actually.Still use below CSS for above example `#meta-container {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
}

#meta {
    width: 25%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 20px;
}`